# Laravel / Blackfire - Composer including autoloader taking significant time

Tags: php, laravel, blackfire

I'm using [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/) to profile my PHP / Laravel application.  Across most endpoints, Composer seems to be taking a long time.  Specifically, the method `Composer\Autoload\includeFile`.  In the example below, it gets called 240 times.

Now I have run `composer dump-autoload --optimize` and I have `opcache` enabled.  Is this behavior normal or is this indicative of an issue?  My understanding would be that the autoloader should only need to be included once.

[image: Blackfire Screenshot 1]
[image: Blackfire Screenshot 2]

Comment: how did you instrument the code to include autoload? I want to do something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autoloader's primary purpose is to load all the various classes in your application. As such, it's likely to call `includeFile` *many* times in a single request.

Comment: thanks for the info, that makes sense.  Beyond running the --optimize-autoloader flag, is there any way to bring this time down or further optimize Composer?

Answer (score 1):

Try dumping autoload in "authoritative" mode with
`composer dump-autoload -a`.

This should yield better performance – I saw about 13% speed improvement on one API endpoint after doing this.

More info: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md